# Access denied when running some remote PowerShell commands

Tags: powershell, winrm, remoting

I have configured WinRM (PowerShell Remoting) on four machines that I administer. On all machines but one I can run both of these commands remotely with no issue. On one cursed machine, `Get-Command` does not work remotely, but `Get-ChildItem` and other cmdlets work just fine.

This works:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName myhost -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem}
```

I get a wonderful listing of my user directory.

This doesn't work:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName myhost -ScriptBlock {Get-Command}
Access is denied
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Command], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand
    + PSComputerName        : myhost
```

Comment: 1) are your running this in an elevated powershell? 2) what if you add the `-credential` parameter to `invoke-command`?

Comment: 1) Yes 2) Adding -credential does not change behavior for both commands

Comment: It sound like you may have a restricted endpoint established there. You might want to review the failing host to review the get-PSSessionConfiguration to see if how that server is different from the one that's working. Additional info on constrained session configuration can be found here "https://4sysops.com/archives/restricting-the-rights-of-powershell-users-with-a-constrained-session-configuration/"

Comment: @Lex: Get-PSSessionConfiguration shows the same configuration for the admin endpoint on the problem host and working hosts. Any other ideas? Get-Module also returns nothing. Access denied when I try Import-Module.